# Excel - CSV file/ the date changed after I save the file

Tags: excel

Thank you for your help in advance

currently, I need to update some my existing CSV file, it is just add a new column, update some value and remove the old column

after i done it, save it.
the date format changed from Picture 1 to Picture 2
you can see the data format from date to some numbers...
can anyone know the reason? and how to avoid?
Thank you.

Before save:

[image]

After save:

[image]

Comment: Excel dates are a pain.  Excel will save dates according to the default settings you have in your copy of excel, and if somebody else opens the file in their copy of excel, you might get another format.  Enter them as strings by preceding the value with an apostrophe

Comment: Excel is IMHO terrible with CSVs. And it's not synonymous with CSV either.

Comment: If you save a file in CSV format from excel, the displayed values are what is saved. Then, if you reopen it in Excel, it will try and interpret the data based on the text. Why do you need to reopen it in Excel?

Comment: Hi All, actually, i am saving the file from CSV to CSV, since i have 50 file required to update the other column value from hours to minutes, i build a Macro to automate it, but, some of them the date changed to strange number, some of them is fine

Comment: But you are doing so using Excel, consider using a good text editor instead

Comment: The format is not changing. The value being saved in the CSV file is the value displayed in the worksheet cell.  The value being saved is NOT the value seen in the formula bar. CSV files cannot save the value stored in the formula bar (unless that is the same value being displayed in the worksheet cell).

Comment: Thank you Ron, but it does matter.... sorry... before save, i put it in power BI, it reckon it is a "Date+Time", after save, it is showing error..... so.... i am not sure why the CSV file changed the value after save? no clue.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it fixed, thank you every one
What I have done is Text the date cell
=if(isblank(cell),"",Text(cell,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM"))
make it to text first, and do the changes, save it, all remain the same
and it allow my power BI read it as a "Data"

Thank you everyone!